# How to access the keys from an object to method

Tags: javascript, html, object, methods

```
var myParser = {
    instr: document.getElementById("pString"),
    v1: [],
    crstr: function() {
        return this.instr.value;
    },
    aV: function() {
        for(i=0;i<this.instr.lenght;i++) {
            if(this.instr[i] == '(') this.v1.push(0);
        }
        return this.v1;
    }
}
```

Above is my object. I want to make a method in my object to access the keys from the object and put a value in v1 array. How can I access the keys from my object in the aV method?

Thank you!

Here is the display code:

```
function pSubmit() {
    document.write(myParser.crstr() + '</br>');
    document.write(myParser.aV());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to access keys from this object? if that is the case, then:

```js
var myParser = {
instr: document.getElementById("pString"),
v1: [],
crstr: function() {
    return this.instr.value;
},
aV: function() {
    for(i=0;i<this.instr.lenght;i++)
        if(this.instr[i] == '(') this.v1.push(0);
    return this.v1;
},
getKeys:function(){
  this.v1 = Object.keys(this)
}}
myParser.getKeys()
console.log(myParser.v1)
```

If you are providing another object, then:

```js
var myParser = {
instr: document.getElementById("pString"),
v1: [],
crstr: function() {
    return this.instr.value;
},
aV: function() {
    for(i=0;i<this.instr.lenght;i++)
        if(this.instr[i] == '(') this.v1.push(0);
    return this.v1;
},
getKeys:function(obj){
  this.v1 = Object.keys(obj)
}}
var foo = {a:2,b:3}
myParser.getKeys(foo)
console.log(myParser.v1)
```

EDIT: I'm still not sure what are you trying to do, but 2 things to fix is **length** instead of lenght, and "this.instr" is HTML element, this.instr.value is string.

```js
var myParser = {
    instr: document.getElementById("pString"),
    v1: [],
    crstr: function() {
        return this.instr.value;
    },
    aV: function() {
      var str = this.instr.value;
        for(i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
            if(str[i] == '(') this.v1.push(0);
        }
        return this.v1;
    }
}

console.log(myParser.aV())
```

```html
<input id="pString" value="(abc)">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I'm trying to put in v1 some values. For example: if my instr is (abc), I want to put in v1 the value 0 if the instr[i] is '('... and I want to make that in the aV function

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!